# Ignore stderr when calling call-shell-region

Tags: call-process

I am having difficulties ignoring the stderr stream of my call to [LuaFormatter](https://github.com/Koihik/LuaFormatter) from Emacs (see [call-shell-region](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html)):

```lisp
(defun rpo-lua-format-buffer ()
  (let ((formatter-cfg-file ".lua-format")
        (formatter-cfg-dir  (locate-dominating-file "." ".lua-format")))
    (if formatter-cfg-dir
        (let* (tmp-buffer-name (make-temp-name "tmp")
                               (tmp-buffer (get-buffer-create tmp-buffer-name)))
          (if (eq 0 (call-shell-region
                     (point-min) (point-max) (concat "lua-format --config=" (expand-file-name (concat formatter-cfg-dir formatter-cfg-file))) nil '(tmp-buffer nil)))
              (replace-buffer-contents tmp-buffer 3)
            (error "lua-format failed."))
          (kill-buffer tmp-buffer))
      #'er-indent-and-cleanup-region-or-buffer)))
```

The error I get, when calling this function (from a `before-save-hook`) is:

```
Error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

However, when I replace the last argument `'(tmp-buffer nil)` of `shell-call-region` with `tmp-buffer` alone, I get stdout and stderr merged in the new buffer.

How can I get rid of the stream content of stderr and only keep stdout?

Answer (score 3):

Your list is quoted, so you are passing in a list with two symbols rather than a buffer and nil. Use `list` rather than `quote`:

```lisp
(call-shell-region (point-min) (point-max)
                   (concat "lua-format --config="
                           (expand-file-name (concat formatter-cfg-dir
                                                     formatter-cfg-file)))
                   nil
                   (list tmp-buffer nil))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help! That solved it. I should definitely learn more about the basics - data types in this case.

Comment: @dubbaluga It's important to understand that `'...` which means `(quote ...)` is not a shorthand for making lists.  It's a form which causes lisp to return, unevaluated, the object that was created by the lisp reader.  Be sure to go over the distinct `read` and `eval` phases of lisp execution.  Once you understand the distinction, `quote` will make much more sense (and you'll be able to avoid related confusions such as inadvertent self-modifying code).